# Simply connectedness of spherical shell

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a spherical shell $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$（the open region between two spheres). I want to show that any closed curve in $U$ can be shrunk into a single point without leaving $U$.

This exercise appears near the section of differential forms. How are they related？

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I showed that any oriented closed curve in$U can be deformed to the same curve with opposite orientation，but I don't know what to do next

Comment: Do you consider that obvious intuitively?

Comment: Yes，that is very obvious. I just don't know how to prove it formally

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Spherical shell is homeomorphic to punctured ball. Indeed, there is an explicit homeomorphism, $x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|}(|x|-r)$ where $r$ is the inner radius.

Step 2: Any path in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homotopic to a polygonal path. Cover the path by balls contained in the open set, take finite subcover, use straight-line homotopy in each ball.

Step 3: Pick any point $p$ on the path and consider the union of line segments $px$, for $x$ on the path. This is a union of finitely many triangles, so it has empty interior. By moving the path slightly, one can make sure this set does not contain the origin. Then the  straight-line homotopy works.